# Why does Git kick me out of the branch after a failed commit?

Tags: git, github

I am new to Git and am having trouble understanding this. Basically here's what happens:

1. I commit and then push my changes to remote repository
2. I get a merge error and fix the files (`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in filename.css. Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.`)
3. I try to commit and push again, but can't because I'm no longer in the branch I was working on  (`error: you need to resolve your current index first`)
4. I try to change branches, but can't because I have files I need to commit
5. Only way I can get out of this is and return to the branch I was working on is with `git reset --hard HEAD`
6. The process repeats

Can anyone tell me what's actually going on here (keeping in mind I'm a newb) and what I should be doing?

**EDIT**:

I am also getting an error with the same files on another branch. I'm not even working on these files and they don't appear when I run `git status`, they only appear as a problem when I try to push. What on earth is going on?

**EDIT 2** - Commands I used:

1. git add . (no errors)
2. git commit (no errors)
3. git push ${project} ${github} (no errors)
4. git merge ${github} (merge errors)

Comment: That definitely doesn't sound normal, when you have merge conflicts you need to merge the issues then commit (as you know), you shouldn't ever get kicked off the branch and this is likely due to your install of `git` on your computer or your .git folder within the project is malformed?

Comment: What error message do you get after step 2?

Comment: @rlee827 Added above

Comment: Git reset --hard doesn't change your branch. Are you sure you're using the word "branch" correctly?

Comment: Did you stage the files with `git add` after fixing them before committing the merge? [The merge conflict section of this link](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) may be helpful.

Comment: In step 3, if you are not able to commit due to unresolved conflicts you could get that kind of error message

Comment: Can you show the exact git commands you run for each step? (Of course, feel free to use mock names for branches, remotes, etc.) Also, provide output for each step.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice added above

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks information

Answer (score 0):

After merge check the

```
git status
```

Find the file with the conflict. Open file chck for >>>> symbols.

It shows why there is conflict .Try to resolve the conflict .

Comment: Oh, I know - that's what I've been doing (step 2)